# 新しい Code of Conduct が議論されています

Tags: 討議, 行動規範

Stack Exchange の ['Be nice' ポリシー](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) (日本語版における[「親切になろうポリシー」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)) を、より正式な Code of Conduct (CoC) とする提案が 7 月上旬に Meta Stack Exchange で為され、現在 CoC の第 2 稿に対するご意見を募集中です。

第 2 稿はこちらでご覧頂けます: [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sgEOl4wP4CIO0rodsplP15_U10bjE3RlMCkA_jI4cMc/edit) / [GitHub PDF](https://github.com/tinkertim/StackCOC)

ご意見はこちらの Meta Stack Exchange で募集中です: [The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/341401)

特に、この新しい CoC が実施されるより前に考えられるべきご意見は 2018 年 7 月 27 日 (金) までに投稿して欲しいとのことです。

以上、お知らせでした <(_ _)>

Comment: 関連: [MSE の Code of Conduct はこのサイトでも採用されますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2734/19110)

Comment: 新しい CoC が本家 Stack Overflow で[公開され始めました](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)。あわせてブログ記事が投稿されました: ["Get to Know Our New Code of Conduct"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/)