# Meta Stack Exchange の Code of Conduct はこのサイトでも採用されますか？

Tags: サポート, 行動規範

Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) で、Be nice ポリシーに代わる[新しい Code of Conduct が議論されています。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2733/19110)この議論はおそらくこのまま進み、何かしらの CoC が策定されることになるでしょう。

そうなった場合、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの「親切になろうポリシー」も変更されるのでしょうか？

変更されるのであれば現在の議論に参加するモチベが上がりますし、翻訳について考える必要も出てくるため、知りたいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

よりお詳しい @aki さんと @NicolasChabanovsky さんにお聞きしたところ、以下のように進むとのことでした。

- 新しい CoC は Stack Exchange Network 全体に影響します。最終版が英語版 Stack Overflow で承認された後、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにも同様のページができます。
- 具体的には、https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior と https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice が書き換わります。
- その後日本語版の中で翻訳を進めていく流れになります。

したがって、現在 MSE で議論されている CoC は将来的にこのサイトにも影響を及ぼすことになります。英語での議論にはなりますが、気になる方は一読なさるのが良さそうです。