# メタ「競技プログラミングの文脈で「WAがでます」と言っているだけの質問は意図がはっきりしませんか？」の修正について

Tags: 討議

「競技プログラミング」の質問を「歓迎する」ということでまとまったと思うので、メタ「[競技プログラミングの文脈で「WAがでます」と言っているだけの質問は意図がはっきりしませんか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2756/)について新の行動規範から見て問題がないかを確認し、問題があれば修正していく作業をして欲しいと思います。

2件の回答について、通報しました。通報すれば「すべての措置はモデレーションチームの裁量によりケースバイケースで行われます。」となっています。その結果を、モデレーションチームより回答をいただきたいです。

作業の進め方ですが、そのメタでは次のような疑問点が残ったままになっています。

- 「「WA」「AC」については界隈では専門用語的に広く使われている言葉なので、そこを書き直してサイトを見るすべての人に通じるように書くべきなのか」
- 「上手くいかないテストケースの具体的な内容を提示できないという欠点を補うのに、似たような間違い方をしているらしい他のコードを出すのでは足りないでしょうか」

疑問点を一つづつ解決していく必要があるので、まず、疑問点をある程度まとめて、それぞれを独立したメタにした方がいいと思います。

次に、回答をどうするかというと、回答をするためには行動規範から結論を導き出して人を納得させられる説明が必要になるので、法律知識が必要になります。日本のコミュニティで回答を作れる人はいないと思うので、StackOverflow社に応援を依頼してはどうですか。現状を説明すれば、StackOverflow社も快く引き受けてもらえると思うし、丁寧な説明もしてくれると思います。

英訳をして回答をもらって、また日本語訳にするのは手間もかかるしニュアンスの違いも出てくるので問題がないわけではありませんが、他にいい方法は思いつかないので、こういう方向で作業することを検討して欲しいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

部分回答になりますが、少なくとも CoC に関する部分はスタック・オーバーフローにおける王道のやり方とは異なります。

> 次に、回答をどうするかというと、回答をするためには行動規範から結論を導き出して人を納得させられる説明が必要になるので、法律知識が必要になります。日本のコミュニティで回答を作れる人はいないと思うので、StackOverflow社に応援を依頼してはどうですか。現状を説明すれば、StackOverflow社も快く引き受けてもらえると思うし、丁寧な説明もしてくれると思います。

スタック・オーバーフローの方針は、ここ「メタ」においてコミュニティ・ドリブンで決まっていきます。基本的には vote を集めたメタ回答の内容が採用されていくことになります。絶対的な正解というものはありませんし、過去のメタ質問に対するメタ回答の vote が変わって方針が変わることもあります。

新しい CoC 自体もコミュニティ・ドリブンで決まりました。 [新しい Code of Conduct が議論されています](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2733/19110) や [The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/341401) によって CoC が現在の形に落ち着きましたが、これはとりあえずの形であって、今後もコミュニティからの要望に応じて変わっていくことが明言されています。

スタック・オーバーフロー設立当初は、その頃のコミュニティ・マネージャーでいらっしゃった @jmac さんからご提案を頂いたこともありました。しかしそこから徐々に誘導して頂き、現在のコミュニティ主導な形になっています。現在でも一応 @NicolasChabanovsky さんに伺うという手段はありますが、これは Nic さんからの回答に盲目的に従うということではなく、あくまで寄せられた回答たちへの vote を参考にするという形になります。

もし @YasuhiroNiji さんがスタック・オーバーフロー内部からの意見で満足できないということであれば、[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) で意見を乞うというやり方が使えると思います。ちょうど最近提案された [多言語サイトにおける機能提案とフィードバックについて](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2748/19110) と似たやり方です。「質問をどうやってモデレートしていけばよいか」というのはサイトのトピックにはあまり関わらない一般的な話題ですので、適した使い方のはずです (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic を参考にしています)。

ただ個人的には、まずは叩き台となるご意見が欲しいと思っています。具体的な問題意識があって初めて建設的な議論ができるので、まずは直接メタ質問して頂いて意見を募るのが最初の一歩になるかと思います。

Comment: 質問を追加しました。通報したので、モデレータの方から行動規範に違反する内容がないかどうか先に説明してもらいたいです。

Comment: 個別ケースの容認できない行為については、「メタ」で議論することは適していません。建設的な議論ができることをメタ質問しましたので協力をお願いします。「初心者への対応について」 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2793/

Comment: 通報に関しては、依然として協議中ですので今しばらくお待ちくださいませ (現在暫定モデレーターは2人しかいないので、それぞれの都合が合ったときにしか合意がとれないのです、すいません)。